# Inconsistent Column Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, range, column

Created a macro on a table with rows which auto expand depending on what is input. The original range of column D which i am working on is D2:D12. On some occasions, the range will go beyond D12. It is important to keep this range for the purposes of sorting. Running a macro to copy all cells (which have formulas) including those beyond D12 and paste them back as values, excel will deny action stating some values lie outside of range (D2:D12). Is it possible to cover every possible range? It is not letting me use D:D stating some values fall outside range

Sub FORMULA_to_value()
'
' FORMULA_to_value Macro
'

'
If MsgBox("Are you sure testing is complete because you can not undo this action?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Range("D2:D15").Select
Selection.COPY
Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub

The macro can be executed if cell D13 has values because it's outside the "table". I need it to have the flexibility to accommodate row extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFAHb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
add these two lines of code:

```
dim MyAddr as string
MyAddr = activesheet.range("D2:D" & Activesheet.cells(rows.count, 4).end(xlup).row).address
```

Then replace "D2:D12" with MyAddr (no quote marks).

Comment: I have edited original post to inclide image and macro formula

Comment: This worked. Forever grateful Justin